# Getting height of UITableViewCell class without subclassing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to calculate the height of a uitableviewcell without doing the whole dance with boundingRectWithSize.

Here's my approach:

```
+ (CGFloat)heightForItem:(id<DDInfoItem>)item
{
    if (!PrototypeCell)
        PrototypeCell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:nil options:nil][0];

    [PrototypeCell configureForItem:item];
    [PrototypeCell layoutIfNeeded];

    CGSize size = [PrototypeCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    return size.height+1;
}
```

Unfortunately, this line

```
CGSize size = [PrototypeCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
```

is returning nil... i suspect because I haven't set up my own constraints since this is not a subclass of UITableViewCell. Can anyone confirm? Is there a simple way of asking the cell to resize itself in this situation?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I still am getting 0 for a height back even thought I've subclassed and added the constraints in IB.

Here's what my constraints on the contentView look like in the debugger:

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170091030 H:|-(NSSpace(20))-[UILabel:0x12766b610]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x178361380 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170094370 V:|-(NSSpace(20))-[UILabel:0x12766b610]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x178361380 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1700992d0 H:[UILabel:0x12766b610]-(NSSpace(20))-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x178361380 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170099500 V:[UILabel:0x12766b610]-(NSSpace(8))-[UILabel:0x127559c20]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170099000 H:[UILabel:0x127559c20]-(NSSpace(20))-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x178361380 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17009c430 H:|-(NSSpace(20))-[UILabel:0x127559c20]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x178361380 )>
```

Note that I have replaced the Prototype cell's initWithStyle:identifier: with a nib loading method.

Also, when i log the size of the labels, they indeed appear to be correctly resizing. The result of calling systemLayoutSizeFittingSize: is still giving me a 0 height however :/

Comment: Your code looks correct for a cell with constraints. However, `UITableViewCell` doesn't have any constraints.

Comment: Don't forget to set the width of the prototype cell to be the table view's width.

Comment: Try setting the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` of your UILabel.

Comment: Hmm that doesn't see, to change anything -- the labels seem as though they are being correctly laid out.

Comment: Could you post a reduced example project at github? I'll look at the constraints etc. and see if I can fix it so it works.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably asking for the height too early in the process. The height is 0 because at that point the height has not been determined yet.

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth, I ended up just doing this:

```
if (!PrototypeCell)
    PrototypeCell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:nil options:nil][0];

[PrototypeCell configureForItem:item];
[PrototypeCell setNeedsLayout];
[PrototypeCell layoutIfNeeded];

return CGRectGetMaxY(PrototypeCell.subLabel.frame) + bottomBufferSpacing;
```

Comment: seems to be. The labels appear to be laying themselves out correctly, but for whatever reason the cell's contentView seems to be unaware that I'd like it to resize to fit the subviews. I am probably missing/misunderstanding a constraint somewhere i guess